# Command OnExecuted not called

Tags: wpf, commandbinding

When I right click on an item in the ListView the event CommandBinding_CanExecute is getting called and Context Menu is displayed. But when I do the same in the empty space of the ListView the event is not fired and Context Menu is displayed but disabled.

Why is CanExecute not called in the second case and is there any workaround to raise this event when clicked in empty space of ListView.

```
<Window.Resources>
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="NewItemCommand" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource NewItemCommand}" CanExecute="CommandBinding_OnCanExecute" Executed="CommandBinding_OnExecuted" />
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <Grid>
        <ListView Background="AntiqueWhite" Name="lst">
            <ListView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="New Item" Command="{StaticResource NewItemCommand}" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListView.ContextMenu>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: What do your ListView items look like?

Comment: I bind List of string to the ListView.

Comment: There's some useful looking discussion here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0413f80d-653f-42f5-ac62-560fa73ff085/contextmenu-for-empty-space-in-listview-not-working?forum=wpf .